# C++ namespace assertions

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-assert

I wrote a templated wrapper class meant to be templated only on types *in* a certain namespace.

Is there a way to `static_assert` that `T` is in `x::` in c++ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a type is from a particular namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974844/check-if-a-type-is-from-a-particular-namespace)

Comment: I think it does and there is no standard way to do it but I can live with it :) (the solution is too intrusive). Thanks.