# Unqualified function call selects function from a wrong namespace

Tags: c++, name-lookup

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    struct Mine {};

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void foo(T1, T2)
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}

namespace B {
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T, T)
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}   

using namespace A;
using namespace B;
// or with the same effect:
//using A::foo;
//using B::foo;

int main()
{
    A::Mine a;
    foo(a, a);
}
```

The program prints `B::foo` instead of `A::foo`. Why does it use `B::foo` instead of `A::foo`?

Imagine the following situation: your library provides a namespace `A` and some other library provides namespace `B` which includes a function template with the same name `foo` as your library. Normally, there is no problem since the correct version can be selected using qualified calls or relying on the argument-dependent lookup. But if the user introduces both `A::foo` and `B::foo` to the same scope using a `using` declaration, the unqualified call is not ambiguous but the wrong function may be selected.

Is there a way to prefer `A::foo` over `B::foo`, since according to the argument-dependent lookup `A::foo` should be selected? What would be your advice in this situation?

Comment: ADL just means namespace A would be searched even if you didn't have `using namespace A;` - it's not meant to (and doesn't) prioritorise `A` over a better match elsewhere. `template <typename T> void foo(T, T)` is a better match - it's more restrictive / specialised.  If you want to take the `B` version out of contention, you could use `enable_if`.

Comment: That's true, but what if you don't have control over what's in namespace `B`? E.g. it may be an external library.

Comment: Do you have control of namespace A?  You could add a `foo(Mine, Mine)`.  Or add one in your own code that calls the `A::foo` implementation.  Or explicitly call `A::foo(a, a)` at each point of use - though that's a bit ugly and may be impractical if you're relying on polymorphic dispatch.

Comment: Yes, namespace A is under my control. But adding `foo(Mine, Mine)` would not help much in the real world - there is not only `Mine`, but in fact many (templated) classes and `A::foo(T1, T2)` should cover all cases where both `T1` and `T2` are defined in namespace A. In the real case we also have a complicated `enable_if` to allow only such type combinations.

Comment: Perhaps you could enable_if based on membership of the `A` namespace?  It's an ugly hack, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974844/check-if-a-type-is-from-a-particular-namespace

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting... But still - if I add `template <typename T> void foo(T, T)` into namespace A, with or without `enable_if`, it will be ambiguous with `B::foo` which does not have `enable_if`. Maybe we should just rename the function, although the real `foo` is the most common and obvious name for it and the problem might happen in the future with other libraries as well... Or should we just tell users not to use `using namespace` or `using`?

Comment: Yeah - it's if they don't use the namespaces A and B, and you want to have forwarding `foo` functions that use `enable_if` to pick between forward-to-A and forward-to-B variants, that you might want that membership-of-namespace hack.  From what you've described, I don't see a better approach based on what you've shown, but perhaps you could have member functions on `Mine` or something instead - hard for us to know what makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually doing the correct thing. Here's the reason.

```cpp
namespace A {
    struct Mine {};

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void foo(T1, T2)
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above code will be matched when there are 2 parameters passed of different (or same) type. Because you've defined both `T1` and `T2` differently (but they can also be same). But the function call is

```
foo(a, a);
```

having both the parameters of same type.
Now a method `foo` with 2 parameters of same type is defined in the `namespace B` as below

```cpp
namespace B {
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T, T)
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And thus the method from `namespace B` is matched, as both the signatures are different.

Try adding the below code

```
namespace C {
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T, T)
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and you'll end up with a compiler error, specifying there's ambiguity in the method definition and then you would have to manually resolve the scope of foo using something like `A::foo(a,a)` or whatever namespace you wish to use.

Comment: Yes, it's doing the correct thing according to the C++ standards, but not according to the programmer's intention :-)

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský Fair enough, but programmer's intention should be based on what the language specifies. That can sometimes be hard with c++ though :)

Comment: Thus should we say, the art of expressing our intentions to computer is called Programming! :P